# Couldn't connect to google instance "google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04

Not able to SSH to an instance from browser or from terminal.
Serial port error shows:

```
google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012
```

Also I tried increasing the disk space from 10gb to 20gb standard persistent disk and restarted the instance .but no luck.
I have also tried by created new instance from the snapshot which also not allowing me to ssh to the instance. also tried changing the IAM role to owner.

Error from terminal says:

```
Authentication failed: Exhausted available authentication methods
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your problem is most likely no free space. You resized the persitent disk, but the OS probably did not resize the root file system. What distribution and version of Linux? I wrote an article that explains the details on resizing an instance: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/ Read my article and then update your question with more details.

Comment: Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS Minimal, amd64

Comment: I read the article but most of the commands that you are using in that article  requires ssh access or gcloud login.In my case both are not working. and not sure how to check  if its really resized the file system .

Comment: Read the part that shows you how to use the serial-port console. You can also mount the disk on another instance to resize/repair. I wrote another article with steps to mount the disk on another instance: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/ Skip the part about UFW.

Comment: I tried creating the new instance and mount the disk, but the new instance also not letting me to do ssh. plus serial port shows some error connecting to my database server.

Comment: If you cannot SSH into a new instance, you have an SSH problem on your side and not the instance. You need to use the correct login and keypair and have port 22 enabled in the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no SSH access to the instance, you can debug the issue in the serial console, you can follow [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) to enable serial console access for a specific instance, once the access is enabled, follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) to connect to the serial port.

You can try the following troubleshoot steps:

1. Reboot the instance

Instances that use the most recent versions of [Public images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) can automatically resize their partitions and file systems after a system reboot.

2. Check your firewall rules

On your local workstation, run the following command:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

If the firewall rule is missing, add it back:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22
```

3. Connect as a different user

The issue that prevents you from logging in might be limited to your user account. For example, the permissions on the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the instance might not be set correctly for the user.

Try logging in as a different user with the gcloud tool by specifying another-username with the SSH request. The gcloud tool updates the project's metadata to add the new user and allow SSH access.

```
gcloud compute ssh another-username@$PROB_INSTANCE
```

4. Check available space

To check space (disk usage) just run the command on terminal

```
    df -h
```

Will list the disk usage and get the output like

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda5        28G   15G   12G  58% /
```

If the root (mounted on /) usage is 100%, you need to clean the tmp directory or restart the machine to make some space on the root.

5. Detach disk and attach it to a new instance

You can detach the boot disk and then attach that disk as a secondary disk on a new instance using the following gcloud commands:

```
gcloud compute instances delete $PROB_INSTANCE \
    --keep-disks=boot 

gcloud compute instances create new-instance \
    --disk name=$BOOT_DISK,boot=yes,auto-delete=no 

gcloud compute ssh new-instance
```

Or you can also do the same using the console following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk).

Comment: If the information was helpful please don't forget to up vote or accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your support. This helped me